# Countability of sets, usage of cantor set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How could I prove that the set $S_1$ of all infinite sequences that consists of 0's and 2's, implies $S_1$ is uncountable. Could I say $S_1$ is equivalent to the cantor set?

Comment: . 
By using the diagonalization argument: so suppose you can count it and $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,\}$ is an enumeration of the sequence. Then constructing a sequence that is not in the enumeration by doing this: the Ith element of the sequence differ with the ith sequence in the enumeration in the ith position

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could. You could also show that the map $$\phi:S_1\to 2^{\Bbb N}\\ \phi(f)= \frac12f$$ is a bijection.